# Xam.Plugin.FilePicker Works fine but can't get file

Tags: android, android-fragments, xamarin, nuget, filepicker

I'm using the Xam.Plugin.FilePicker NUGet version 1.1.0 on a Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 Fragment and when I use the file picker it works fine but when I get a file the byte array is empty and the file name is only the name of the file without the path.

If only I could get the file's full path it would be great, from there I could get the byte array. I am doing something wrong? my code is like this:

```
try
{
    var crossFilePicker = Plugin.FilePicker.CrossFilePicker.Current;
    var myResult = await crossFilePicker.PickFile();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(myResult.FileName)) //Just the file name, it doesn't has the path
    {
        foreach (byte b in myResult.DataArray) //Empty array
            b.ToString();
    }
}
catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    ex.ToString(); //"Only one operation can be active at a time"
}
```

Also if you use the back button it won't let you pick andother file because "Only one operation can be active at a time"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested the file picker plugin for xamarin forms android. 
It can get the file byte, I can output the file bytes. Your code is right please check what the file type you selected or you may selected an error file. In my site, I selected a jpg file:

[image]

> If only I could get the file's full path it would be great

You can not get the file path now, but this function will coming soon. Please check the github repository [commit branch](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows/pull/31/commits/a0a5bcfe70dc08152486306d5356127ad25d91f5).

> Also if you use the back button it won't let you pick andother file because "Only one operation can be active at a time"

This issue is also fixed on the way, please check the [github repository](https://github.com/Studyxnet/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows/issues/16)

If you can not wait for them to fix, I suggest you to download the source code and change it by yourself.

Comment: I downloaded the code but still had an error when getting the path, checking the code I found in IOUtil.class a TODO to handle non-primary volumes... adding the exact same code "return Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/" + split [1];" fixed the path and it is working fine now, I will put this observation also in the gitpage, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

for "Path" you should download the GitHub code that has this property. Nuget package is a bit old